# Failed to installing https using express 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ssl, https

I thought I have implemented it right already but it doesn't work. I started the server it shows both

Express server listening on port 3001
Express server listening on port 3002

```
    var express = require('express');
    var config = require('./config');

    // Models
    var User = require('./models/User');

    // Controllers
    var userController = require('./controllers/user');

    var app = express();

    mongoose.connect(config.mongodb);
    mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

    app.set('port', 3001);
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(sass({ src: path.join(__dirname, 'public'), dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public') }));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


    //home
    app.post('/homeStats', userController.ensureAuthenticated, homeController.index);
    //create profile    

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
      res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
    });

var secureServer = https.createServer({
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ssl/example.com.ca-bundle'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/example.com.crt')
  }, app)
  .listen(HTTPS_PORT, function () {
    console.log('Secure Server listening on port ' + HTTPS_PORT);
});

    app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });

    module.exports = app;
```

Any thought?

Comment: hide the part .listen(HTTPS_PORT..................) and the run i think it will run on single port.